# Verificar contraseña encriptada en PHP

Tags: php

he estado realizando una web y me surgió un problema el cual no puedo encontrar la solución (y eso que ya lo he programado antes) pero es un código simple que siempre he copiado y pegado y lo comprendo, pero no veo el error la verdad.
Estoy intentando verificar una contraseña encriptada para iniciar un SESSION pero por alguna razón no me toma la condición como válida y me da el mensaje de "datos ingresados no son correctos". Debe ser un error bobo pero la verdad no lo veo.
Agradecería si me ayudan a ver por qué ocurre esto

Este es mmi codigo:

SIGNUP.PHP

```
if (!empty($_POST['username']) or !empty($_POST['fullname']) or !empty($_POST['mail']) or !empty($_POST['password'])){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,fullname,mail,password,tipo,sanciones,estado) VALUES (:username,:fullname,:mail,:password,0,0,0)";
    $insertar = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $insertar->bindParam(':fullname', $_POST['fullname']);
    $insertar->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $insertar->bindParam(':mail', $_POST['mail']);
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $insertar->bindParam(':password', $password);
    if ($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirm_password']){
      $insertar->execute();
      echo "<script>location.href='login.php';</script>";
    } else {
      $contraseñas_diferentes="CONTRASEÑAS NO COINCIDEN";
    }
  }
```

LOGIN.PHP

```
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
$records = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, fullname, username, mail, password FROM users WHERE username=:username");
$records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$records->execute();
$results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])) {
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
  echo "<script>location.href='signup.php';</script>";
} else {
  $dato = '<img src="css/error.png" alt="" width="15" height="15"> Los datos ingresados no son correctos.';
}}

<form action="login.php" method="POST">
  <div><label>Ingresa tu username <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su username"></label></div>
  <div><label>Ingresa tu contraseña <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña"></label></div>
  <div><label><?php echo $dato; ?></label></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Ingresar"></div>
  <div><span>¿No tienes cuenta? <a href="signup.php">Create un usuario</a></span></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Y cómo se guardó la contraseña? Pregunto porque dices que copiaste el código, entonces esa parte no es trivial.

Comment: Pregunta: la contraseña que tenes en la DB esta encriptada? Porque la que estas comparando aca, llamada $_POST['password'] en ningun momento se encripta. Tendrias que usar la misma funcion y la misma sal que usas para encriptar lo que se guarda en la BD, para codificar la pw que acabas de ingresar, y se compare de esta manera.

Comment: Si, la contraseña esta encriptada, la he guardado en una pagina signup simplemente con un PASSWORD_BCRYPT

Comment: Lo he agregado para que puedan ver el método que utilicé

Comment: Bien, pasale a $_POST['password'] la misma funcion para encriptar y luego compara. Si no configuras una sal, esta se generará aleatoriamente, lo que muy probablemente te devuelva error al comparar. Recomiendo configurar tu propia sal.

Comment: Lo he probado y sigue sin tomarme la condición, que lo haya copiado no significa que no lo entienda, sé lo que hace el código, solo que al no conocer la función necesitaba saber si había algo que no debería o si agregar. Pero no, sigue sin funcionar

Comment: ¿El problema es en `login.php`? Aplica un `trim` al dato del POST: `if (password_verify(trim($_POST['password']), $results['password'])) {`

Comment: Hola y gracias por la respuesta, si, es en el login y no pasa nada, simplemente no me cumple con esa condición. Aun con el trim tampoco me lo valida jajaja la verdad ya no sé que puede ser

Comment: ¿Depuraste que la consulta esté trayendo datos con un `var_dump($results);`, depuraste el post con `var_dump($_POST);`? No sea que estés comparando sobre datos vacíos. Y, ¿revisaste el log de errores? Es un amigo desconocido que te pude ahorrar horas de depuraciones y dolores de cabeza. Es la hora de aprender a revisarlo.

Comment: Si, lo he probado, con el `var_dump($_POST);` viendo que resultados me devuelve y el post trae obviamente el valor ingresado y `$results` el valor encriptado. Para ser mas exacto devuelve: `array(2) { ["username"]=> string(6) "marcos" ["password"]=> string(45) "$2y$10$uvLd4brdOiirWi2DqqOI4OMbXqew8IgWcNZc88" } array(2) { ["username"]=> &string(6) "marcos" ["password"]=> string(3) "asd" }`

Answer (score -1):

Probablemente no está encontrando el registro en la base de datos, revisa si hay datos en tu fetch antes de usarlo:

```
$records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$records->execute();

$records->store_result();
echo $records->num_rows === 1 ? '<p>Registro encontrado</p>' : '<p>No se encuentra registro</p>';

$results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])) {
...
```

Si el fetch tiene datos es necesario comprobar los valores dentro de `$_POST['password']`  y `$results['password']`

Comment: `store_result()` y `num_rows` no son de PDO, sino de `mysqli`. El OP está usando PDO, por tanto el código dará un error fatal.